# How to disable Visual Studio App Centre SDK in debug builds in android?

Tags: android, azure, visual-studio-app-center

How can I disable crash and analytics services provided by the Visual Studio App Center SDK in debug builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which language/framework are you using? Xamarin, React Native, Flutter, Java, Kotlin? If you are just using Java, you can use this solution.

Android has an inbuilt API for BuildConfig, so you can just put your AppCenter initialization code within this code block

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  AppCenter.start(getApplication(), "{Your App Secret}", Analytics.class, Crashes.class);
}
```

If this doesnt work, let me know